# Use the pumping lemma to show that following language is not context-free

Tags: proof-explanation, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I was wondering if someone can help explain this question. I've been stuck on it for a while and having a hard time with it.

Use the pumping lemma to show that following language is not context-free
L={a^k b^m c^n ∣ k>m>n≥0}

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This problem should be suitably similar to the example given on the Wikipedia page for the pumping lemma for context-free languages such that adopting that proof should work